# Does BeautifulSoup 4 resolve external DTD entities?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml, dtd, tei

I have a TEI document containing characters encoded as `&stern_1;` which are mapped in a separate `Zeichen.dtd` (Document Type Definition) file. The file `Zeichen.dtd` contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ENTITY stern_1 "&#10035;" >
```

I am using `BeautifulSoup4` and `lxml-xml` as a parser.

Example:

```
dtd_str = '<!DOCTYPE Zeichen SYSTEM "Zeichen.dtd">'
xml_str = "<p>Hello, &stern_1;!</p>"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(dtd_str+xml_str, 'lxml-xml')
print(soup.find('p').get_text())
```

The code above prints this:

```
 Hello, !
```

instead of this:

```
 Hello, ✳!
```

I also tried inline DTD, with the same result:

```
dtd_str = """
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY stern_1 "&#10035;">
]>
"""
xml_str = "<p>Hello, &stern_1;!</p>"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_str, 'lxml-xml')
print(soup.find('p').get_text())
```

output:

```
Hello, !
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems you never put the doctype and p-tag strings together. You always just lookup the xml string, so I suppose the custom character is never loaded.

Comment: yes, it should read `BeautifulSoup(dtd_str+xml_str, 'lxml-xml')`, but this doesn't change anything - the issue still persists

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a working solution to my own problem:

```
dtd_str = """
<!DOCTYPE html [
    <!ENTITY stern_1 "&#10035;">
]>
"""
xml_str = "<p>Hello, &stern_1;!</p>"
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(dtd_str + xml_str)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(etree.tostring(tree, encoding='unicode'), "lxml-xml")
print(soup.find('p').get_text())
```

will print this:

```
Hello, ✳!
```

which is exactly what I wanted. The lxml library handles the dtd files correctly, whereas BeautifulSoup has a much nicer and more intuitive API when you need to walk through the tree.